# (Python Crash Course 16.8): json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert [this](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson) json file into a more readable one.
However, I'm getting an error message:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My code is:

```
import json

file = 'data/1_month.geojson'
with open(file) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)
    readable_file = 'data/readable_eq_data.json'

with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)
```

What might be a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in the `1_month.geojson` file, probably an invalid character at the beginning of the file. Instead of saving the data locally I suggest you download it directly from the website using `requests`

```
all_eq_data = requests.get('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson').json()

with open('readable_file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know you can do that. That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me other than encoding.
Please re-check your json file (for example re-downloading).

```py
path = r'your\path\Downloads\1.0_month.geojson'

import json

with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)
    
readable_file = path + '.readable.json'

with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: The Windows backslashes seem to beg for clarification. There should be no reason to not use forward slashes, which work on Windows, too. If you are supposing that the file has been downloaded into an obscure nested subdirectory, maybe also explain this assumption.

Comment: @tripleee I downloaded that file from browser, so I just copied that path.

Comment: That path will depend on your OS, your browser, and your configuration.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, so I add 'your\path' to imply that.

Comment: Definitely some characters that require encoding.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it really was something with the file. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

While the OP asks for a python solution, I also wanted to share a one-liner that does this easily. Depending on your OS, you may have or can install a UNIX command called `json_pp`. It provides a prettified JSON output to stdout, which you can easily write to file. All you need is `curl` and this UNIX command:

```
curl https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson | \
json_pp > readable_file.json
```

You'll get something like:

```
{
   "metadata" : {
      "status" : 200,
      "api" : "1.10.3",
      "title" : "USGS Magnitude 1.0+ Earthquakes, Past Month",
      "url" : "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson",
      "generated" : 1626877469000,
      "count" : 8488
   },
   "type" : "FeatureCollection",
   "features" : [
      {
         "type" : "Feature",
         "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
               -150.9063,
               61.6748,
               45.8
            ]
         },
         "properties" : {
            "url" : "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak0219aazwl5",
            "code" : "0219aazwl5",
            "net" : "ak",
            "nst" : null,
            "types" : ",origin,",
...
...
```